# Create dynamic events in socket io with flask

Tags: javascript, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have been trying to solve a problem with event handlers with flask-socket.io. I manage to append some html code, but now I want to create a event handler with the new HTML code. It is possible? This is the client side:

```
    socket.on( 'busqueda', function(msg) {
$('#listcanciones').append('<div class="row justify-content-center no-gutters mb-5 mb-lg-15" id="'+msg.id+'" style="cursor: pointer;"> <div class="col-lg-3 text-center"><img class="img-fluid" src="'+msg.foto+'" alt=""></div> <div class="col-lg-3 text-center"><div class="bg-black  h-100  text-center" style= "width: 300px ;margin:0px auto"><div class="d-flex h-100 text-center"><div class="project-text w-100 my-auto text-center text-lg-left"><h4 class="text-white">'+msg.nombre+'</h4><p class="mb-0 text-white-50">'+msg.artista+'</p><hr class="d-none d-lg-block mb-0 ml-0"><h4> </h4><p class="mb-0 text-white-50">Votos: '+msg.votos+'/20</p></div></div></div></div></div>');
});
```

I create an id to manage the div, and with statics divs that I have stored I dont have any problems, I create the event handlers for the stored data like this:

```
{%for i in range(0,cont)%}
$('#{{canciones[i]['idcancion']}}').on('click',function(event) {
   socket.emit('my_event', {id: '{{canciones[i]['idcancion']}}'});
 return false;
});
{%endfor%}
```

Is there a way to dynamically create events?
Thank you.

Comment: You can use JavaScript APIs (or jQuery or other frameworks) to set up event handlers that emit the data that you need.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thank you!!